# Read individual key presses (integers) in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am aware of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25768509/read-individual-key-presses-in-powershell) but it doesn't answer my current question.

I know that the current line gives me the next pressed key:

```
$Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey().Character
```

For example, if I press `1`, I get `1`.

But that is a string (well, actually a char), I want the number as an integer.

I try with:

```
[int]$Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey().Character
```

And:

```
$Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey().Virtualkeycode
```

But in both lines, if you press `1`, you instead get `49`.

I know that I can simply do:

```
[int]$Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey().Character - 48
```

But I was wondering if there is any better way to do that. For example, if I want to get both letters and numbers, the usage of `-48` would make a bit more difficult, since I would need to use some conditional blocks.

So, my question is: **Is there any better way to get the pressed key (number) as integer rather than `[int]$Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey().Character - 48`?**

Comment: It's not a string actually, it's a char.

Comment: @marsze, ohh, I didn't know that. I am new in Powershell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An option you have is the `System.Int32.Parse` method:

```
PS> [int]::Parse

OverloadDefinitions
-------------------
static int Parse(string s)
```

In use:

```
$in = $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey().Character
[int]::Parse($in)
```

---

You can also use `System.Int32.TryParse` if you think the user will enter something non-integer:

```
PS> [int]::TryParse

OverloadDefinitions
-------------------
static bool TryParse(string s, [ref] int result)
```

In use:

```
[int] $out = 0
$in = $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey().Character
if ([int]::TryParse($in, [ref]$out)) {
    $out
}
else {
    Write-Warning 'Non-int entered!'
}
```

Comment: Yes, definitely use TryParse!

Comment: You answer works, but I would prefer to wait some time before accepting it. By the way, in order to use TryParse I had to modify `[int]$out` to `[int]$out = 0`. Otherwise I get `NonExistingVariableReference`.

Answer (score 4):

Another approach:

```
$int = switch -regex ([console]::readkey($true).keychar) {'[0-9]' {[int]"$_"}}
```

*(Will return `$null` if non-numeric character entered.)*